# after beforeSubmit method in jqgrid which method i need to call for submit

Tags: jqgrid

I am using `jqgrid` in `mvc 4`. I have one problem. after calling `beforeSubmit` method in `jqgrid` which method i need to call for submit values to server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your `beforeSubmit` callback don't returns correct results. The callback allows to skip submitting by returning `[false, "error description"]`. If `beforeSubmit` don't detect any problem and want to process submitting it should return `[true]`. So you should just add

```js
return [true];
```

at the end of your `beforeSubmit` callback.

Comment: beforesubmit is returning [true,''], but after that which method i need to call for submitting values to server.  My code here.                                   jQuery("#gridMain").navGrid('#pagernav', { add: true, addtext: 'Add', edit: true, edittext: 'Edit', del: true, deltext: 'Del', search: true, searchtext: 'Find', refresh: true }, //options
{ reloadAfterSubmit: true, beforeSubmit: function (postdata, formid) { return [true, ""]; } }, // edit options
{ reloadAfterSubmit: true, beforeSubmit: validate_add }, // add options
{}, //del options
{} //search options
);

Comment: @pavan: You should nothing to do. You should verify that `validate_add` returns `[true]`  or `[true, ""]` too. jqGrid should automatically submit the data to the server if the `beforeSubmit` returns array with `true` as the first element.